# Can't Upload Products images to DigitalOcean CDN?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product-images, media-images, cdn

I have Integrated DigitalOcean CDN with Magento2.2.7 version.
I can get images from CDN successfully but when I am uploading product images then it is not uploading to CDN directly.
Is required any Extension to upload Images to CDN?